# After extracting code to lib widget is no longer working

Tags: android, android-appwidget, library-project

I had a perfectly working widget as part of my project. Then I decided to extract common code (including the widget) into the library project. After doing this everything works except the widget. It appears in the list of widgets available for addition but when I place it on the desktop all I get is this toast message: "Application is not installed on your phone". Can someone shed light on this?

Neither configuration nor code has changed. Widget definition exists in both meta files (project and lib) with project metafile containing absolute (including path) names and all permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've ran into the same problem today. However I guess I've found an answer.

Check the correctness of `android:configure` element in AppWidget metadata XML file. If you have widget configuration activity, probably its class name or package has changed when you extracted widget to different project.

Now system cannot find activity that you mentioned and complains with cryptric "Application is not installed on your phone".

Comment: I think I went wrong route on conversion. I just did it by converting exiting project to library and then creating brand new project that uses it and everything works now. Thanks for your answer I'm going to accept it

Comment: I just want to stress that it might as well have to do with the lack of activity declaration in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score -1):

Put into manifest:

```
<intent-filter
   <action android:name="com.mypage.activityConfig" />
</intent-filter>
```